# Entity framework by hand without designer

Tags: entity-framework

Maybe my google fu is sucking but I can't find any tutorial on how to use Entity framework without using the designer in Visual Studio. Is there a way to use Entity framework without the designer?

Comment: Are you talking about *Code-First*? There are thousands or tutorials covering it. Start with http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [code first](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) approach (it requires EFv4.1 or newer) where the mapping is defined in code (or by default mapping conventions) or you can create EDMX file from scratch - it is [XML file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399604.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

They are two ways:

Classical (database first): You can learn about xml EF files on [msdn **.edmx File Overview (Entity Framework)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982042.aspx)

> An .edmx file is an XML file that defines a conceptual model, a
>   storage model, and the mapping between these models. An .edmx file
>   also contains information that is used by the ADO.NET Entity Data
>   Model Designer (Entity Designer) to render a model graphically.

New (code first): They are a lot of resources. Here a [MS code first video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2010/DEV212).